# How to develop dynamic nested lists for mobile using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, dom-events

I am developing a mobile application using jQuery mobile and spring MVC. In application I am using nested lists, but these nested lists are not working in Symbian (Nokia-E71,...) mobile because these mobiles are not supported jQuery.

**How to develop nested lists without using jQuery?** I tried using html tags but total nested list is displayed in the home page. I want the nested lists like the following.....

1. whenever click on a menu the main menu will disappear and the sub-menu of the particular menu will be displayed.
2. If the menu doesn't have sub-menu, it will display a form.
3. It will support up to 5 levels of menus and sub-menus.

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init() {
    var myStyleTweaks = new StyleTweaker();
    myStyleTweaks.add("AppleWebKit/420+", "resources/static/tweaks/S40webkit.css");
    myStyleTweaks.add("Maemo", "resources/static/tweaks/maemo.css");
    myStyleTweaks.tweak(); hideDiv(); toggle_secondlevel();
}
addEvent("onload",init);
```

and I tried using multiple div's but my menus contain relationship to one another to display, please give me any idea...

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Menu Test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function toggle(element)
         {
            if (element.style.display != "none") {
               element.style.display = "none"
            } else {
               element.style.display = "block"
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('menu1')); return false">Menu 1</a>
            <ul id="menu1" style="display: none">
               <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('menu2')); return false">Menu 2</a>
            <ul id="menu2" style="display: none">
               <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but my application is Mobile application. I have lot of menus and submenus then it is displaying scroll. So I need the list like when I click on menu, all the menus will be hidden and submenus of that particular menu will be displayed.